# Generic Parameter "T" could not be inferred

Tags: swift, xcode, generics

I am trying to create a generic func that compares the identider of two models and return nil if theres no equal identifier. Here's the function.

```
func compareModel<T: ObjectIdentifier, U: ObjectIdentifier>(model: T, models: [U]) -> (index: Int?, model: U?) {

        for (index, m) in models.enumerate() {
            if model.identifier == m.identifier {
                return (index, m)
            }
        }

        return (nil, nil)
    }
```

I access it like this:

```
let object: (index: Int?, model: Checkout?) = self.compareModel(checkout, models: currentJoborders)
```

But I'm getting this error from the compiler.

> Generic Parameter "T" could not be inferred.

Comment: What's the type of `checkout`?

Comment: It's a struct Model.

Comment: Could you please post a [mcve]? Without seeing what you're trying to call `compareModel` with, it's difficult to say what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your `Checkout` struct didn't implement `ObjectIdentifier` protocol.

Make sure you define your model struct as `struct Checkout: ObjectIdentifier { ... }`

More over your func should looks like:

```
func compareModel<T: ObjectIdentifier, U: ObjectIdentifier>(model: T, models: [U]) -> (index: Int, model: U)? {
    for (index, m) in models.enumerate() {
        if model.identifier == m.identifier {
            return (index, m)
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Use it as:

```
let currentJoborders: [Checkout] = [...]
let checkout: Checkout = ...

if let object: (index: Int, model: Checkout) = compareModel(checkout, models: currentJoborders) {
    print(object)
}
```